# Why is this wrong? Making 10 Components within 1 pane easily

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jlabel, jtextarea

Before i begin, i have this whole pane being opened as an action. I was wondering why if I run this program, it doesn't output 10 lines of equations, with text areas to the right of them. It outputs a window, with nothing inside.
(Program is being run in a different part of the code- this is a snippet.)

`

```
    pane2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 

     GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints(); //Creates New GBC

     if (shouldFill) 
        {
            //natural height, maximum width
            d.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        }

     if(multiTable >= 1 && multiTable <= 12)
     {
         for(int r = 1; r <= 10; r++)
         {
             int[] answer = {1};
             JPanel[] prob = new JPanel[10];
             JLabel[] probOutput = new JLabel[10];
             JTextArea[] uAnswer = new JTextArea[10];

             prob[r] = new JPanel();
             rand1 = random1.nextInt(12)+1;
             rand2 = random1.nextInt(2)+1;
             answer[r] = multiTable * rand1;
             if(rand2 == 1)
                probType =( r+") "+multiTable+" x "+rand2);
             if(rand2 == 2)
                probType =( r+") "+rand2+" x "+multiTable);

             probOutput[r] = new JLabel(probType);
             d.gridx = 0;
             d.gridy = r;
             pane2.add(probOutput[r], d);
             uAnswer[r] = new JTextArea();
             d.gridx = 1;
             d.gridy = r;
             pane2.add(uAnswer[r], d);
         }
         frame2.add(pane2);
         frame2.pack();
     }
 }`
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/NsqM7AZk) is a link to a pastebin link for the full program (It's a school program I don't care for much, just need the grade.)

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: How certain are you that 1 ≤ multiTable ≤ 12 when you run?

Comment: It is certainly between 1 and 12, there are check boxes that the user selects one of and it set's multiTable to the number they select (1 - 12).

Comment: Check the bottom of the code box for the full thing if you would like to run it yourself.